# How to display custom context menu during create feature task?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, arcgis-9.3

I have a created a custom context menu using `ICommandBar` and am displaying it on create feature mouse-down right click. I am constructing a point collection on each mouse down and then creating a polyline. For each point I am refreshing using `EditSketch.RefreshSketch()`.

On right click, I created a custom context menu to finish the sketch.  Sometimes, I get the  default "Sketch Tool/Select Elements" context menu, which I do not want to get on right click.

The code that I'm using to display the context menu:

```
public override void OnMouseDown(int Button, int Shift, int X, int Y)
{
  if (Button == 2)
  {
    _objContextMenu.Popup(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS Desktop are you developing for?

Comment: arcGis Desktop 9.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'short circuit' the `OnContextMenu` and tell ArcGIS that everything's sorted.

```
public override bool OnContextMenu(int X, int Y)

{
      return true; // or allow some condition where the context menu is allowed
}
```

Comment: My apologies for the one line answer, I was in a hurry when I wrote it. In order to dismiss the existing context menu one must override the OnContextMenu then you can use the OnMouseDown (if Button == 2) for a right click. The coordinates given for the OnMouseDown are in screen coordinates from the application (ArcMap) window, once you know ArcMap's location add it to the X and Y to set the form properties me.Left and me.Top (I think that's VB but C# has something similar).

Comment: The IWindowPosition object will give you the location of the ArcMap frame, this post discusses the windows location of the screen display [link](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=202668)